# I need to make a list of of the multiples of 3 and 5 based on a previous number list Example: input[8,5,3.10] output[5,3,10] but output is not adding

Tags: python, list

```
def multiplos(listOfNumbers):
    Multiples =[]
    i=0
    x= len(listOfNumbers)
    while i < x:
        if len(listOfNumbers[i]) % 5 == 0:
          Multiples.append(listOfNumbers[i])
        i+=1
    return Multiples

numeros = listaNum()

print(multiplos(numeros))
```

Comment: Make this change in your `if` statement: `if ((listOfNumbers[i] % 5) == 0 or (listOfNumbers[i] % 3) == 0):`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```py
def multiplos(listOfNumbers):
    Multiples = []
    i = 0
    x = len(listOfNumbers)
    while i < x:
        if listOfNumbers[i] % 5 == 0 or listOfNumbers[i] % 3 == 0:
            Multiples.append(listOfNumbers[i])
        i += 1
    return Multiples
```

Stylistically, it's probably better to write it as a for-loop instead of a while-loop:

```py
def multiplos(listOfNumbers):
    Multiples = []
    for n in listOfNumbers:
        if n % 5 == 0 or n % 3 == 0:
            Multiples.append(n)
    return Multiples
```

You could even use a list comprehension instead:

```py
def multiplos(listOfNumbers):
    return [n for n in listOfNumbers
            if n % 5 == 0 or n % 3 == 0]
```